# when a certain number of clicks has been reached, then change the image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to build a cookie clicker for a project. With each click on an image, the clicks are counted and displayed. Now I want the image to change automatically after 10000 clicks, i.e. a new image replaces the old one and the current number of clicks is saved in local storage.

It doesn't quite work for me. Only when I save the page and then reload it is the picture changed and not automatically.

```
    if (clickercount >= 10000) {
        $(".clickImg").attr("src", "new_image.png")
    } else {
    }

    $('#saveButton').click(function () {
        saveCurrentStatus()
    });

    $('#resetButton').click(function () {
        localStorage.clear();
        location.reload(true)
    });
```

Comment: Put your `if clickercount` code *inside* the saveButton click function (or better, put it in its own function and call it both onload and in the click event)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the information above, it seems like you are only **executing the code once**. And that happens only when you **load the page**. You could use an **event listener** to listen for **clicks** on your **cookie**, and run the piece of code in the event listener.

```js
$('.clickImg').click(function () {
    if (clickercount >= 10000) {
        $(".clickImg").attr("src", "new_image.png")
    } else {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I interpret your code correctly, then the if-else block only runs on the first load. You should check that on each click event. Maybe at the end of `saveCurrentStatus`, or even better, create a `checkClickCount` function, and append it to the click event handler.